# QGIS 1.7.1 and PyQT4 conflict: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: qgis, plugins

I've just started playing with QGIS with a view to eventually developing a few simple plugins in Python. I downloaded `QGIS 1.7.1` for Windows and started working through [these](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/index.html) workshop notes.

If I've understood correctly, developing plugins often uses `QT Designer` and something called `pyuic4`. These don't seem to be included in the QGIS install, so I downloaded [PyQT4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) separately. This enabled me to finish working through the workshop, but now when I start QGIS I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
RuntimeError: the PyQt4.QtCore module is version 1 but the qgis.core
module requires version -1
```

If I uninstall PyQT4, the problem goes away, but then I don't have `QT Designer` or `pyuic4`, so how do I develop plugins? I'm not sure what `version -1` of PyQT4 is.

Does anyone have any suggestions, please? I'm obviously doing something daft, but I'm not sure what. Perhaps QT Designer *is* actually included somewhere with QGIS 1.7.1, but if so I can't find it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install the OSGeo4W version of QGIS? If you did, you'll have pyuic4 available through OSGeo Command line.

I'm not using QT Designer but QT Creator on Win 7 (has to be installed separately), maybe that makes a difference.